# Curl returns result but php doesn't

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I found very interesting bug. When I run cmd:

```
curl https://example.com
```

I see result, but when I run php script:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch) . "\n";
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

I see:

> Error: Operation timed out after 10002 milliseconds with 0 bytes
>   received

I tried to test many options but I didn't found a good solution.

edit: Time is not problem. I can change timeout on 1200s and it doesn't help.

Comment: Is the website you are trying to fetch large?

Comment: A lot of code? 32 KB

Comment: Does the command line version finish in less than 10 seconds?

Comment: I forget. Time is not problem. When I changed timeout 1200s it didn't help.

Comment: Probably an SSL problem. You can disable verification by using: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: @iainn - yes, when I added `--connect-timeout 10` - works

Comment: @ARN - I tested it. Didn't help :(

Comment: Are you running the curl command and the php-script from the same machine? If not, make shure curl is working allright on the machine where php runs. It could be a resolving issue (wrong dns of gateway settings). You can also try to do file_get_contents("https://example.com"); and see what it gets.

Comment: @ARN ok I tested `file_get_contents` on my machine - the same result as php-script. And I tested php script and curl on other machine. Php script doesn't works, curl - works...

Comment: enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_STDERR,($stdout=fopen("php://output","wb")));` , then post the verbose log. most likely it's being blocked by a firewall or something tho.

Comment: @hanshenrik  -> https://pastebin.com/yB6i5N4M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going by the CURLOPT_VERBOSE log you posted in the comments, you're not trying to connect to example.com , you're trying to connect to www.opentable.com , and opentable.com doesn't respond to requests that doesn't have any User-Agent. it worked with the curl cli program because curl cli has a default user-agent, but it doesn't work with libcurl, because libcurl doesn't have an user-agent by default. set an User-Agent header to connect to opentable.com.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"libcurl/".curl_version()["version"]." PHP/".PHP_VERSION);
```

Comment: I used useragent, for example: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A` and it didn't help. Thank you!